# Versionamento de Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

estou com uma dúvida meio que conceitual.

Atualmente estou trabalhando num projeto em que vou ter que versionar as chamadas de algumas api's. Por exemplo:

```
Urls: /api/V1.0/Chamados/1220
      /api/V1.5/Chamados/1220
```

A diferença entre as duas chamadas é que a versão 1.5 irá retornar alguns campos a mais. Só que o sistema utiliza Stored Procedures (e eu não tenho autonomia para mudar essa condição... tem que ser assim e ponto final).

Como faria para NÃO ALTERAR a procedure que atende a versão 1.0? Seria o caso de duplicar a procedure e adicionar os campos? Alguém conhece algum tipo de abordagem diferente?

Comment: é possivel executar outra query e adicionar ao resultado final junto com o resultado dessa procedure?

Comment: Seria interessante você colocar um exemplo prático da forma que trabalha atualmente para dar uma idéia de soluções

Answer (score 0):

Passa  um parâmetro com a versão para a procedure e baseado na versão informada você faz o retorno dos dados.